# iOS - FileManager won't delete json file in document directory

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I created a file in the document directory and for some reason when I try to delete it using the code below, it doesn't get deleted. The code doesn't throw any errors, but the file is still there

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
if let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
    let filePath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("data.json")
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath.path)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I also tried to put it inside another folder and remove the folder but still the same problem.

This is the path where the file is stored :

```
Users/user1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/76AFDB69-75C8-464E-93F2-6ABF622068FD/data/Containers/Data/Application/7D268156-977A-4A3C-834B-6B13FA3DE76D/Documents/
```

Comment: have try to put condition like file exist at path and also print the full path after appending path component

Comment: ohh I just figured what was wrong . It's because after this code I do perform segue which brings another view controller and preventing the file manger from deleting the file. smh !

Comment: Please check fileExit or not and also test on device because in simulator every time you run application new Device ID:- **7D268156-977A-4A3C-834B-6B13FA3DE76D** generate.

Comment: Unrelated but there is also a *remove* API which takes an URL parameter: `try fileManager.removeItem(at: filePath)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like below

```
if let filePath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("data.json"), fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath.path)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The code doesn't throw any errors, but the file is still there

No, it isn't. The problem is with the way you are checking to see whether "the file is still there". You are looking *on your computer* for the file. But iOS files are *sandboxed*. At the time you are looking, the path where the file was is completely different from your claimed path:

```
Users/user1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/76AFDB69-75C8-464E-93F2-6ABF622068FD/data/Containers/Data/Application/7D268156-977A-4A3C-834B-6B13FA3DE76D/Documents/
```

Such paths are not permanent. They are meaningless and should not be used. The only way to know whether the file is still there is with more code from inside iOS, i.e. *ask the FileManager*. When you do, you will find that you are, indeed, deleting the file successfully.